# Boolean Validation returning wrong values when returning data from Jquery Dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I ran into a new headache. Can anyone tell me when the number 2500 > 30 is false? This is the type of headache I am running into now, and this messes with my JQuery UI since I require these boolean validations to work.

This is what I have:

```
function execute () {
        amountReturn = ($('#modalInputAmount').val());
        console.log(amountReturn);
        console.log(available);
        var isValid = (available < amountReturn)? false : true;
        console.log('AmountReturn:' + amountReturn + ' ; available:' + available + ':' + isValid);        
        if ((isNaN(amountReturn)) || !(isValid)) {
            $('#amountDialog').dialog('close');
            $("#weHaveANaN").dialog("open");
        } else {
            //dosomething         
        }
}
```

So, After I open the dialog for the first time on my page, it works hunky-dory. After closing it however, and reopening it, it works only sometimes.  Literally only sometimes. The correct values from amountReturn and available are always received. But, to the darker side of things, I get this response now:
[image: Weird return]

As I noted, the values are returned from a Jquery Dialog Input box. This should still not interfere with my boolean expression though, and as seen here, the amountReturn (2500) which is more than the available(30), should be invalid, where it is stamped as valid.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This question was hard to explain.  

Feel free to check www.chaoticRequiem.com, click the (add to cart) button, enter an arb value, and then do the same for multiple other buttons

Comment: And keep the F12 console open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure but you could do parseInt first before comparing, like

```
var amountReturn = parseInt( $('#modalInputAmount').val(), 10);
var available = parseInt( available, 10 );
//then compare
var isValid = (available < amountReturn)? false : true;
```

Comment: Again, you saved the day. Got like 3 hours left to finish this cart, I have a job interview about it tomorrow for a junior developer .

Comment: Just don't know why I am not spotting things like these. been developing for 3 years now.  must be pressure